# Calculate total upload/download data size

Tags: c#

In my c# application(.net framework 4) I download data from(using HttpWebRequest class) a url, the fetching process should repeat in a certain time interval. Now I want to calculate the total upload and download data size(in KB). How can I get the upload/download data size in each web request?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTTP Header property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the header info.  [Content length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should give you the size in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx

Answer (score 1):

once you get the WebResponse and read the data with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx you get the bytes read every time. if you += a static variable that keeps track of the totals in your class, you can have an acurate and up2date count of your download bytes. Same goes for uploading.

To go from bytes to kilobytes, you divide by 1024.